# What's the actual value of CSS {background-image: initial }

Tags: css

We know the value of:

```
 a {background-image: url("../../media/example/let.png");}
```

How to know the actual value?:

```
a { background-image: initial }
```

Comment: it's `none` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: You find the initial value by reading the specification for that property.

Answer (score 0):

background-image: initial 
would just be default... which is no image :)
At least I think that is what you're asking, if not my bad.